# Run the ASP .NET web application under a different user than the current user

Tags: asp.net, iis, credentials

IIS is utilizing the current logged-user's credentials to access an ASP.NET application. Is it possible to create a login page on the application and pass another users credentials, so that  particular web app is run under a different user?

Answer (score 2):

Disable impersonation, should you have enabled it (most likely not) and set the Authentication in IIS to Anonymous with the Account you wish to run under:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324274